# How do I make my plotted line in Autoplot.zoo different colors? How to add soft gridlines in the background?

Tags: r, ggplot2, zoo

I am struggling to find a way to make my plotted data a different color such as "palegreen2" instead of black. This is my code. Please let me know what I can put into my code.

```
p <- autoplot.zoo(SP500)
p + labs(title = "SP500",
              subtitle = "(1997-2018)",
              caption = "Data from Yahoo Finance (^GSPC)",
              x = "Date",
              y = "Billions of Dollars",
              colour = "palegreen2") + theme_classic() + 
         theme(plot.title= element_text(hjust=0.5, margin = margin(t=0, r=0, b=5, l=0)), 
         axis.title.y = element_text(margin=margin(t=0, r=10, b=0, l=0)), 
         axis.title.x = element_text(margin=margin(t=10, r=0, b=0, l=0)),
         plot.margin = margin(1, 1, 0, 0, "cm"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two cases are taken into consideration in the following code, I hope this solves your problem

```
## packages
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)

## simulation data
x=zoo(matrix (rnorm(30), nrow = 10), as.Date("2008-08-01") + 0:9)

## Case 1 All lines are drawn in one plot 
p=autoplot.zoo(x,facets = NULL)
p+scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1")+
  theme_bw()

## Case 2 Lay out panels in a grid
p1=autoplot.zoo(x, colour='red')
p1$mapping$colour=rep(c('green','red','black'),rep(10, 3))
p1 + scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1",
                        labels = c("four", "six", "eight"),
                        name = 'Name')+
  theme_bw()
```